# Mongo query count number of field based on string after a $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to query the number of calls after a certain date, sum their duration time, group them by groupId, and then count the number of participants who are active/inactive. The active/inactive state is represented by a string.

I have tried searching the documentation and stackoverflow about the syntax of doing a conditional sum of the state, but I cannot find any examples of doing so after doing a $group

```
db.calls.aggregate(
{ 
    $match : { createdAt: { $gte: ISODate("2019-05-02 18:58:46.284Z") } }
},
{ 
    $group : { 
       _id : "$groupId", 
       totalCalls : { $sum : 1 },
       totalDuration : { $sum : "$duration" },
       totalInactiveState : { $count : "state.active" },
       totalActiveState : { $count : "state.inactive" }

    }
})
```

Comment: please provide us a sample document and the expected document. so that we can further help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) can get you what you need. It is basically a conditional statement to run an `if` scenario

```
db.calls.aggregate(
{ 
    $match : { createdAt: { $gte: ISODate("2019-05-02 18:58:46.284Z") } }
},
{ 
    $group : { 
       _id : "$groupId", 
       totalCalls : { $sum : 1 },
       totalDuration : { $sum : "$duration" },
       totalInactiveState : { $sum : { $cond: [{'state.active': false}, 1, 0 ] } },
       totalActiveState : { $sum : { $cond: [{'state.active': true}, 1, 0 ] } }
    }
})
```